# Match date in two cells with conditional formatting, +/- 3 days.. Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a deadline sheet for office.
I have made a conditional format that compares the dates with our "office are closed"-dates provided by our HR-department. If the delivery date match any of the "office closed"-dates in the next column it will be coloured red.

This works fine, but I just noticed one thing. If the date where 1 day before the holidays, and the holidays would be many days a row starting next day, we wouldn't see that and we would probably get big trouble manage Finnish these masters before deadline as we are not at office for a few days.

So, I thought, maybe I could add to the script something that says: "compare the dates in this column with the dates in "Office Closed"-column, if there is a match within a range of 5 days, color it red...?

Is this something I can do?

here is a screenshot of the sheet.
[image]

This is the code I use in Conditional Formatting now:
=COUNTIF($L$4:$L$25,H6)>0  which works fine.

Thanks for any help!
/Andreas

Comment: update in question: So, I am looking for some way to look at the right hand side column (The "closed office days") and say, "hey, if this date, plus minus 3 days from that, appears in the left hand side column, please color that red for me.." Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following formula in CF:

```
=IF(LEN(A2),SUMPRODUCT((($C$2:$C+3)>=A2)*(($C$2:$C-3)<=A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey man, I believe it worked! Thanks!! Your a genus  I will just check all the dates now but it looks great! Thanks again!